# My Hammer.js code does not work with IF condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, hammer.js

I am using jQuery and Hammer.js to modify the style properties of my website when I "tap" on the screen on the smartphone.

I have 3 elements : `img#icone-bijagos`, `p#texte-bijagos` and `a#lien-bijagos`. The link `lien-bijagos` is related to the image `icone-bijagos`. The text `texte-bijagos` opacity is set at `0` in the CSS.

When I first "tap" I want the opacity of the text to become `1`, and I don't want the link to activate itself. On the second tap, I want the link to activate itself.

I figured I would use an `if` condition : `if opacity==="0"`, then `opacity==="1"` and `pointerEvents==="none"` (to deactivate the link), and if `opacity==="1"`, then `pointerEvents==="auto"`. But it doesn't work.

When I tap on the screen the first time, the text appears and the link doesn't activate, but when I tap a second time, nothing happens.

```js
var iconeBijagos = document.getElementById("icone-bijagos");
if (document.getElementById("texte-bijagos").style.opacity === "0") {
  Hammer(iconeBijagos).on("tap", function(event) {
    document.getElementById("lien-bijagos").style.pointerEvents === "none";
    document.getElementById("texte-bijagos").style.opacity === "1";
  });
} else if (document.getElementById("texte-bijagos").style.opacity === "1") {
  Hammer(iconeBijagos).on("tap", function(event) {
    document.getElementById("lien-bijagos").style.pointerEvents === "auto";
  });
}
```

```css
#icone-bijagos {
  position: absolute;
  left: 41%;
  top: 40%;
  width: 2%;
}

#icone-bijagos:hover {
  width: 2.2%;
}

#texte-bijagos {
  position: absolute;
  left: 43.5%;
  top: 37%;
  opacity: 0;
  color: #ff9600;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#bijagos:hover #texte-bijagos {
  transition-property: opacity;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="bijagos">
  <a href="www..." id="lien-bijagos">
    <img src="www..." id="icone-bijagos">
  </a>
  <p id="texte-bijagos">La géologie des Bijagos</p>
</div>
```

Comment: `=` is not a comparison operator,

Comment: `=` is assignment. `==` or `===` should be used to check for equality. Voting to close as a typographical error

Comment: Thanks, but when I change my = by ===, it doesn't work as well

Comment: Do you realize that once you bind the event it will never attach the other. event to go back?

Answer (score 0):

[`element.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ElementCSSInlineStyle/style) returns the inline styles applied through the `style` attribute of the element. Not the styles applied though css classes.

Use [`window.getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) which returns the current styling of the element through any means applied.

```js
var iconeBijagos = document.getElementById("icone-bijagos");
var texteBijagos = document.getElementById("texte-bijagos");
var lienBijagos = document.getElementById("lien-bijagos");

var texteStyle = window.getComputedStyle(texteBijagos);

if (texteStyle.opacity === "0") {
  Hammer(iconeBijagos).on("tap", function(event) {
    lienBijagos.style.pointerEvents = "none";
    texteBijagos.style.opacity = "1";
  });
} else if (texteStyle.opacity === "1") {
  Hammer(iconeBijagos).on("tap", function(event) {
    lienBijagos.style.pointerEvents = "auto";
  });
}
```

```css
#icone-bijagos {
  position: absolute;
  left: 41%;
  top: 40%;
  width: 2%;
}

#icone-bijagos:hover {
  width: 2.2%;
}

#texte-bijagos {
  position: absolute;
  left: 43.5%;
  top: 37%;
  opacity: 0;
  color: #ff9600;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#bijagos:hover #texte-bijagos {
  transition-property: opacity;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="bijagos">
  <a href="www..." id="lien-bijagos">
    <img src="www..." id="icone-bijagos">
  </a>
  <p id="texte-bijagos">La géologie des Bijagos</p>
</div>
```

---

**Update after comments**

You will need to use one `tap` handler and do the testing inside that

```js
var iconeBijagos = document.getElementById("icone-bijagos");
var texteBijagos = document.getElementById("texte-bijagos");
var lienBijagos = document.getElementById("lien-bijagos");

Hammer(iconeBijagos).on("tap", function(event) {
  var texteStyle = window.getComputedStyle(texteBijagos);

  if (texteStyle.opacity === "0") {
    lienBijagos.style.pointerEvents = "none";
    texteBijagos.style.opacity = "1";
  } else if (texteStyle.opacity === "1") {
    lienBijagos.style.pointerEvents = "auto";
  }

});
```

Comment: Doesn't work as well. When I do the first tap, the HTML changes so that the style:opacity:1 appears in my <p id=texte-bijagos>, but nonetheless, the styles doesn't change the second time I tap.

Comment: @ Gabriele Petrioli ,done that as well, still doesn't work :(

Comment: @Moussolene there was an error in both my snippets as the code setting the style used `===` instead of `=` so not setting occurred. i have updated it now

Comment: thank you I have changed it as well, but still doesn't work.